# Close button in review queue not working when viewing duplicate

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

In the Close Votes review queue a post can be voted as duplicate. The duplicate which was flagged is available in the queue interface to allow to compare the two posts easily.

When I'm in that queue I do as follows: I read the original post, I click on the <kbd>Duplicate</kbd> button, I read the duplicate, and if I agree I want to press the <kbd>Close</kbd> button that has the tooltip `agree with this close vote`. However, in this case the button does not do anything. It shows up as clicked (visible by a blue border) but the close dialog does not show up (in fact the screen does not change at all). Screenshot (from TeX.SE):

[image]
To actually cast the vote I first need to click on the <kbd>Question</kbd> button again, which shows the question that is to be voted on, and only then the <kbd>Close</kbd> button works as expected.

Note that the close dialog does seem to be present in the page source. The Inspector in Firefox shows the following when the button is clicked while the duplicate target is viewed:

[image]
The dialog is however not shown on the page itself.

Proposed bug fix: could the UI be changed to make the button work (i.e., show the close dialog) when viewing the duplicate?

Browser: Firefox 79.0 (64-bits) on Ubuntu 18.04.